# need to set a timer for in javascript , then clear

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to create a timer in JavaScript.  I see the `setTimeout(fn, 100)` but unclear how to wrap this so it will clear itself at the end.

I tried doing

```
var buttonTimer = null; 

$scope.backButton = function() {

    if(buttonTimer === null){
        $history.back();
    }

    buttonTimer = setTimeout(function(buttonTimer){
        buttonTimer = null;
    }, 100);

}
```

The whole point is to prevent the user from hitting this function too quickly.. and ignoring all subsequent clicks within that `100ms` window, at the end of the window, clear the timer and resume accepting clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing angular, I prepared a plnkr for demonstration:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5qrslKpmkglXTvEyYgBr?p=preview

Your code is almost Ok, the only problem is that you start a new timeout on every click. The effect is, that the callback fires multiple times and resets `buttonTimer`.

So the only change is:

```
var blocker = null;
$scope.backButton = function() {
  if(blocker == null) {
    blocker = setTimeout(function(){
      blocker = null;
    }, 1500);

    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
  }    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use throttle from lodash/underscore or Ramdajs. 
for example

```
$scope.backButton=_.throttle(100,function(){/* do something here */});
```